# iOS emoji messed up in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, encoding, emoji

I am using a open source UILabel subclass `STTweetLabel v2.22` ([Github](https://github.com/SebastienThiebaud/STTweetLabel/releases/tag/2.2.2)) and trying to show emoji in the label. During my test it seems that the code can handle most cases correctly but sometimes I see this:

[image]

Just wondering why this could happen, and what could be a possible fix I should look into..

Thanks!

-- Update (adding code used to decode strings from server) --

```
 NSData *data = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSString *decoded = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: Hello @Allan Jiang , I am also facing this issue can you help me? you got any solution ?

Comment: @JayMehta I didn't got any effective solution. I switched to some other library

Comment: Can you please provide other library name ?

Answer (score 2):

Hi I have got one solution for that library you can find height with emoji.
Please use `<CoreText/CoreText.h>` framework and use below code.

```
  - (CGFloat)heightStringWithEmojis:(NSString*)str fontType:(UIFont *)uiFont ForWidth:(CGFloat)width {

    // Get text
    CFMutableAttributedStringRef attrString = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
    CFAttributedStringReplaceString (attrString, CFRangeMake(0, 0), (CFStringRef) str );
    CFIndex stringLength = CFStringGetLength((CFStringRef) attrString);

    // Change font
    CTFontRef ctFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef) uiFont.fontName, uiFont.pointSize, NULL);
    CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attrString, CFRangeMake(0, stringLength), kCTFontAttributeName, ctFont);

    // Calc the size
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString);
    CFRange fitRange;
    CGSize frameSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), NULL, CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX), &fitRange);

    CFRelease(ctFont);
    CFRelease(framesetter);
    CFRelease(attrString);

    return frameSize.height +4;

}
```

Let me know thoughts....!!!

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

Do not use `encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding`, emoji are not ASCII. Use `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

Why are you converting to `NSData` and then back to an `NSString`? That makes no sense.

There is something else going on here.