# AMAttributedHighlightLabel not working properly in UITable View?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, label, uilabel

I have use AMAttributedHighlightLabel for show "#"hashTag and "@"Mention name clickable but AMAttributedHighlightLabel properly work in uitable view. It will call touchesBegan method but not found that word. So that it will not fire delegate method.[Table Label Image Link](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/6177191/6764176/e69fa46e-cfc9-11e4-9d5d-297ae172b80a.png)

LINK THIRD PARTY CUSTOM LABEL [AMAttributedHighlightLabel](https://github.com/rootd/AMAttributedHighlightLabel)

**Code**

```
    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
    int count = [touchableLocations count];
    for (int i=0; i < count; i++)
    {

        if (CGRectContainsPoint([[touchableLocations objectAtIndex:i] CGRectValue], touchLocation))
        {
            NSMutableAttributedString *newAttrString = [self.attributedText mutableCopy];
            [newAttrString removeAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName range:[[touchableWordsRange objectAtIndex:i] rangeValue]];
            NSString *string = [touchableWords objectAtIndex:i];
            if([string hasPrefix:@"@"])
                [newAttrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:self.selectedMentionTextColor range:[[touchableWordsRange objectAtIndex:i] rangeValue]];
            else if ([string hasPrefix:@"#"])
                [newAttrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:selectedHashtagTextColor range:[[touchableWordsRange objectAtIndex:i] rangeValue]];
            else if ([string hasPrefix:@"http://"])
                [newAttrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:selectedLinkTextColor range:[[touchableWordsRange objectAtIndex:i] rangeValue]];
            else if ([string hasPrefix:@"https://"])
                [newAttrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:selectedLinkTextColor range:[[touchableWordsRange objectAtIndex:i] rangeValue]];
            else if ([string hasPrefix:@"www."])
                [newAttrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:selectedLinkTextColor range:[[touchableWordsRange objectAtIndex:i] rangeValue]];
            self.attributedText = newAttrString;

            currentSelectedRange = [[touchableWordsRange objectAtIndex:i] rangeValue];
            currentSelectedString = [touchableWords objectAtIndex:i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is any of the code called? You say that it passes in `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, but does it goes through the `if` test? What are the values?

Comment: hi @Larme it will check "if"  condition but do's not match corditionates that store in array touchableLocation.

Comment: When user touch on hash tag at that time  touch method called and i will get that point (CGPoint) touchLocation = (x=145, y=39) and in array list that value ,Printing description of self->touchableLocations:
<__NSArrayM 0x7f8034239990>(
NSRect: {{413, 1.8450000286102295}, {8, 17}},
NSRect: {{421, 1.8450000286102295}, {9, 17}},
NSRect: {{429, 1.8450000286102295}, {8, 17}},
NSRect: {{437, 1.8450000286102295}, {8, 17}},
NSRect: {{444, 1.8450000286102295}, {8, 17}},
NSRect: {{452, 1.8450000286102295}, {7, 17}},
NSRect: {{459, 1.8450000286102295}, {8, 17}}
)

Comment: Actually i have tried same library with UITableView. and i received all events. can you please tell me that what is hierarchy of your UILabel ? 
like UITableVIew --> UITableViewCell --> UILabel. This is my hierarchy that i am using to test senario and it working fine.

Comment: Hi @JatinPatel , This is my hierarchy UITableView->CustomCell->View->View->Label . Please check it. Let me know if any suggestion.

Comment: Hello @Jay Mehta, I have tried same hierarchy and its working fine. One things i suggest you that there should be difference between as initial you are storing NSRect in Array and the position that you received while tapping  on same link. so i think this difference is due to its hierarchy. let me know if i can help you.

Comment: Hi @JatinPatel it work fine with 1 or 2 line but when number of line increase at that time it will not working properly. Many other people also facing same issue that i found in googling.Can you please provide your demo code ...?

Comment: Hello @Jay Mehta, now i am able to face problem as you faced. the Rect calculation of the string using  `AMAttributedHighlightLabel` library is not accurate so i would like to suggest you to  used [STTweetLabel] https://github.com/SebastienThiebaud/STTweetLabel library.

Comment: Hi @JatinPatel , I have used STTweetLabel library but in that library have problem with emoji character. Have you any idea ? [link]https://github.com/SebastienThiebaud/STTweetLabel/issues/129
Thank you for your response.

Comment: Hello @Jay Mehta, can you please send me sample text that you are testing(that have emojis)so i am directly test same text on STTweetLabel demo..

Comment: Hello @JatinPatel Please see given link in that i have used emoji character [link]https://github.com/SebastienThiebaud/STTweetLabel/issues/129 with Label border.

Comment: Hi @JatinPatel, I have found solution for STTweetLabel issue please refere below [STTweetLabel]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25128643/ios-emoji-messed-up-in-uilabel/29429606#29429606 In that show my answer that given.

Comment: @Jay Mehta, grate. Currently i am developing library that support link, @, #, image, font etc. so once it completed  i will inform you. may that help out of such cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have face some issue in AMAttributedHighlightLabel Library so that i have move to [STTweetLabel](https://github.com/SebastienThiebaud/STTweetLabel) Library.This is good library but i have found [issue](https://github.com/SebastienThiebaud/STTweetLabel/issues/114) in STTweetLabel when emoji characters are use in text it will cutting down some text on label so that i will use this code of below

`#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>`

```
   - (CGFloat)heightStringWithEmojis:(NSString*)str fontType:(UIFont *)uiFont ForWidth:(CGFloat)width {

            // Get text
            CFMutableAttributedStringRef attrString = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
            CFAttributedStringReplaceString (attrString, CFRangeMake(0, 0), (CFStringRef) str );
            CFIndex stringLength = CFStringGetLength((CFStringRef) attrString);

            // Change font
            CTFontRef ctFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef) uiFont.fontName, uiFont.pointSize, NULL);
            CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attrString, CFRangeMake(0, stringLength), kCTFontAttributeName, ctFont);

            // Calc the size
            CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString);
            CFRange fitRange;
            CGSize frameSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), NULL, CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX), &fitRange);

            CFRelease(ctFont);
            CFRelease(framesetter);
            CFRelease(attrString);

            return frameSize.height + 5;

        }
```